# List items dependent on a time limit

Tags: mysql

Im trying to come up with an SQL query that will list the rows that are within a certain time span which depends on the current time. The function which will call this query will check if the user is in the system, otherwise it will list him as absent.

[image: Table]

So a class starts at 9:00 for example, the query should compare the ScheduleTimeStart and ScheduleTimeEnd, with the current time. The query should list a row only if the time is 9:00 and onwards, but do not list a row if the current time exceeded the 30 minutes cooldown period. So in other words from 9:00 - 9:30.

What I have done so far:

```
SELECT studentID, scheduleID, scheduleDate, scheduleTimeStart, scheduleTimeEnd, schedule.classID, schedule.unitsID 
FROM schedule 
JOIN schedule_students USING(scheduleID) 
JOIN students USING(studentID)
WHERE scheduleDate=CURDATE()
AND scheduleTimeStart >= CURTIME() //Gordons answer
AND scheduleTimeStart < CURTIME() + interval 30 minute// but its not working
AND studentID=1003;
```

Comment: So what have you got so far, show us your query

Comment: The 1st Question has been updated

Comment: Your scheduled items seem to span an entire hour, beginning and ending on the hour.  What record should be listed if the current time is 30 minutes past the hour?

Comment: With this Function I would like to check if the student with specific student ID, Date and time has a class. With this Querry, if the statements are rigth it will return one row. Then Ill count the results and if count ==1 then return true, otherwise false. Thats the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn to use parameters.  Don't munge SQL strings with values.  This can lead to syntactic errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM schedule s
WHERE scheduleID = ? AND classID = ? AND unitsID = ? AND
      DATE(scheduleDate) = CURDATE() AND
      scheduleTimeStart >= CURTIME() AND
      scheduleTimeStart < CURTIME() + interval 30 minute;
```

It is not clear if you want the same condition on the `scheduleTimeEnd` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. Is it possible to give me an explanation what  + interval 30 minute does?

Comment: @Bobys . . . It adds 30 minutes to the time.

Comment: I dont know why but interval returns NULL when I use CURTIME() but, it works fine if I use NOW(). Unfortunalty my records are not using the NOW() format, but only the time.

Comment: @Bobys . . . `curtime()` works when I try it in MySQL.  I supposed you could also try `time(now() + interval 30 minute)`.